# How do I give a letter a value to use in math in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, math

So I want to make a blackjack program, I have made an list of all the cards and a dictionary of the values of each named card (a.e. K : 10, J : 10 etc.) How can I make it so that when a card is randomly selected, and that card happens to be a named card, that that card converts from its letter to its corresponding number? I need it to calculate the sum of the dealt cards and while I can use "except ValueError: card == 10" it feels like working with the problem instead of solving the problem, and it doesn't work for ace.  I'm sorry if this question sounds chaotic or completely idiotic, I just started with programming.

Comment: Use the dict. Do you know how to lookup a value from a dict? And do you know how to check if the card is in the dict, in some form or another? e.g. `in`, `dict.get`, `except KeyError`.

Comment: Also, why doesn't your solution work for aces? I'm not super familiar with blackjack. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: My solution doesn’t work with aces because they are either 11 or 1, depending on the total sum of the dealt cards. And both obviously aren’t equal to 10

Comment: Oh, OK, then it sounds like you need to put aside aces to be calculated after. That's a separate problem.

Comment: Also I wanted to use the dict but I don’t know how to implement it, as the dealt cards are random so you can’t just type dict[letter] as you don’t know which letter it’s going to be

Comment: But the dict contains all the letters, no?

Comment: It does, but the cards go from 2 till 10 and then there are 4 with a letter

Answer (score 0):

So Instead of using an easier way I don't know about, I used a try and except block for both the players and the dealers cards. I probably overcomplicated it for myself but hey, it works.